# Obtain download link using Postman

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

I am currently pentesting a digital download site.

It occurred to me that if I can set specific parameters and send a request to a specific URL, is it possible to get the "send download link to email after completing purchase" URL? I could then send a request validating this request with the right parameters and actually obtain that product for free.

The reason I'm asking this and not doing it is because to get the URL, I would have to purchase something, which at minimum is 20 bucks, and who would want to waste 20 bucks for a small piece of string that might not even be vulnerable to attacks. Btw, the tool I use is Postman.

Comment: Just ask the customer to invalidate the "purchase" afterwards. Get it in writing that they will invalidate the purchase and refund the money, if necessary.

Comment: But im asking that is it or has it ever been possible to do this?

Comment: Whether or not that is possible depends on the server. If the server is set up properly, then it is not possible. But it's very well possible that the server is not set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes. Practically (and hopefully), no. HTTP transactions being stateless, proof of payment is in the form of a token that denotes payment. The token (or tokens) would typically be encrypted, highly random and be a mix of something that identifies the customer and something random.

To successfully replicate this, you would have to know the exact parameters, guess the values of the parameters and any cookies, correctly set any other headers the server expects and make the request within the specified validity window for the token (if a timeout has been established).

So, to answer your question on "is it or has it ever been possible to do this" - it is possible. But a properly implemented solution would make it *impractical* to carry out such an attack. It doesn't matter if the client side tool is a browser or Postman.

Comment: Good answer. I would like to add that, if the request for the download link is a POST request, it's easier to create that custom link with Postman or cURL than with a browser.

Comment: Lets say the token aint encrypted. And i have the token. I do this by first creating a normal payment session. Through that i have the token. Because i will have the url, i will most probably have the exact parameters and headers. Now can i use curl to send a request to validate my payment without actually paying. I am now willing to spend some money to test this. I dont know if u know about this, but a year ago, a guy was able to delete any video on youtube without being authorized using this method. I am imagining another form of this.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. But here are the unknowns - is the unencrypted token random or static? Is it pegged to a user or a session? Payment transactions are POSTs, meaning they are probably protected by a nonce (CSRF, replay protection etc), and there may still be a validity window. Let me underscore that I am not saying it is not possible. All I'm saying is a GOOD payment system makes it very, very difficult to carry out. If not, every hacker worth his salt would be carrying these attacks out.

Comment: So what could this attack be called. Also lets say that the token is random. And it is pegged to a session. Also, what countermeasures(as you mentioned csrf protection etc) can protect against this and how.Thanks man.

Comment: This is a mix of so many, I'd be at a loss to naming it. Cross-site-fixation with a dash of token prediction? Definitely a cross-site attack, since this wont be originating from the application. Countermeasures - CSRF protection, token randomization, encryption, using POST... OWASP would be the best place to get a solid deck of these cards.